Hidden directories in fzf-tab plugin
I have this line in my .zshrc file:
zstyle ':fzf-tab:complete:cd:*' fzf-preview 'ls --color=always $realpath'

It works well. When I type "cd" command and TAB key, the shell show a list of directories, but not show hidden ones. I have tried to add "-a" on "ls" but the result is the same.
zstyle ':fzf-tab:complete:cd:*' fzf-preview 'ls -a --color=always $realpath'

I have used "exa" and "eza" instead of "ls", but nothing works. There is something wrong?

What is stored on $realpath?

I'm not sure, but I think that you can use any name

So what's the point then of this parameter expansion? Actually, where did you find this documented? I have never worked with fzf, but I searched a bit and could not find any fzf-preview command at all. Only fzf --preview and fzf-preview.sh came up.

BTW, I can't imagine that you can choose any name instead of realpath. This name is most likely determined by fzf; how should it work otherwise? For debugging (and understanding what is goin on), I suggest that you put a print -u 2 "realpath=$realpath; ls -a .... into the command. Once you understand the purpose of this variable, you can perhaps use the knowledge for finding a better solution to your problem, instead of the hack in your answer.

It's possible, I'm a newcomer in zsh., In fzf-tab plugin page you can find an example: https://github.com/Aloxaf/fzf-tab?tab=readme-ov-file#configure.

The link you sent is nice, but IMO does not help us here. I still think that you should try to print realpath and tell us here, so that we have something to work.

I answer myself.
According to a github question (https://github.com/Aloxaf/fzf-tab/issues/193), you need to add this option in .zshrc file:
setopt GLOB_DOTS


This has the possiblr disadvantage, that it affects all globbing in your shell. When you now do a simple ls * in your shell, you will see the hidden file as well.

Yes, but I haven't found any other way to do it

I don't know how the string after fzf-preview is actually used by zsh, but it would be worth trying to write it as setopt localoptions dotglob; ls -a --color=always $realpath instead.

Or maybe, to be really on the safe side, with an anonymous function: fzf-preview '() { setopt localoptions dotglob; ls -a --color=always $realpath }'. Let me know if this works. Don't forget to do a setopt NOGLOBDOTS before your test it, lest you don't know whether it works due to the old setting or the new definition.

Keep in mind that "ls -a" is executed for fill the preview window. My problem is in the list of directories that plugin show when you type "cd + TAB". Without "setopt globdots" the plugin only show not hidden directories. For example, if you are in home directory, ".config" is not showed.
